# Dev->Stage->Prod with Git deployment for Azure Websites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-git-deployment

How best should I accomplish the following deployment objectives with Git deployment for Azure?

- Easily switch when working locally to either use fake in-memory data or (eventually) non-production snapshot of real data
- Deploy to staging environment on Azure such that at first I could use fake in-memory data and eventually move to non-production snapshot of real data.
- Deploy to production with real data

I currently deploy using Github and a staging branch to a staging Azure website. Since I deploy to a public repo, the web.config file is ignored by git. (**EDIT**: I just learned that ignoring web.config actually causes deployment error on azure)

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually supposed to be simpler than that. Please see [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Managing-settings-and-secrets). Basically, the idea is that you set some AppSettings in the Azure portal to override the default values that are committed to your repo.

Comment: I did, David. And I read your blog as well. The problem was Azure wouldn't deploy through Github without web.config being present in the repository (even though it was manually uploaded to wwwroot via FTP). And I needed to keep the _real_ connection string locally to connect to SQL Azure **and** get it deployed but without it being visible in the public Github repository.

Comment: Another ideal solution would have been to have a "fake" web.config in Git which would take real values at runtime on Azure and "transform-on-build" the web.config locally via something like web.local.config. But I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Note that the Azure build is almost identical to doing a 'Deploy to file system' in VS. So presumably you could repro that same issue locally. Your alternate solution using transform-on-build should have worked as well in theory. BTW, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuregit/threads is probably a better place for git Azure issues.

Comment: I'll give transform-on-build another try based on this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) by Scott Hanselman

Answer (score 0):

Well... Here's what I did that works for me right now.

- To quickly switch between fake in-memory data locally, I use a compilation symbol `LOCAL` and a preprocessor directive `#if LOCAL`.
- Same compilation symbol works when you deploy to Azure, so I can work on fake data until I'm ready to switch to real db. I can also use the app settings if I really want to make to switch it more easily.

The challenge was to keep a web.config with "secrets" (like connection string) locally and not expose it to Github. I added it to .gitignore, but then my deployments started failing on Azure because it could not find the web.config. Just copying it to wwwroot via ftp did not help - Azure was looking for web.config in the repository.

So, to make this work I "slightly" altered the deployment process by first copying the Web.config from wwwroot to the repository before running the default deploy.cmd. This was simple - this is what you do:

1. Create a `.deployment` file in the root of your repository with the following:

   [config]
   command = deploy.my.cmd
2. Create `deploy.my.cmd` with the following script:

   xcopy %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\Web.config %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\\ /Y

   deploy.cmd

Now, I have web.config with secrets locally. Git ignores this file. I uploaded the correct web.config to Azure via FTP, and it gets used whenever I deploy.